# stack around the variable was corrupted. Почему возникает данная ошибка и как от неё избавиться?

Tags: c, функции, обработка-ошибок, стек

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{

    double* m, j, n;

    printf(" j:    char: start address %p extent %ld\n", &j, sizeof(j));
    printf(" n:    char: start address %p extent %ld\n", &n, sizeof(n));
    printf("*m: pointer: start address %p extent %ld\n\n", &m, sizeof(m));
    
    m = &j;
    j = 5.5;
    n =  1.7;
    printf("Before m+=1 j=%p\tm=%p\n\n\n", &j, m);
    m += 1;
    printf("After  m+=1 j=%p\tm=%p\n", &j, m);
    *m = 1. - n + 1;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Ошибка]
[image: Результат]

Я хочу понять почему выдаётся ошибка stack around the variable was corrupted.
Наверное, данная проблема происходит при смещении указателя на 8 байт назад (для указателя double* и переменной j double) или же на 8 байт вперёд относительно переменной такого же типа (в результате, например, если взять два последних байта адреса переменной j и затем сместить на 1 байт -> F728 +/- 1 = F720/F730, то указатель будет указывать на байты с таким адресом (F720 или F730), а затем я попробую в них (в этот и другие 7 байт, лежащие дальше) что-нибудь записать через разыменование, то выводится ошибка, если же сместить назад или вперёд на большее количество байт (m += 200 / m -= 100) и записать туда какое-либо значение, то ошибки не будет).
*m = (float)*a - n + (int)*x; - Если убираю эту строчку, то ошибка уже не выдаётся.
Почему так происходит? Там же не должна находиться граница стека. И почему если я пытаюсь записать какое-либо значение через указатель, ссылающийся на определённый объект с типом соответствующим типу указателя, в область рядом с тем объектом, куда указывает указатель, то выдаётся такая ошибка, с другими типами пробовал и такая же ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При проверке стека (`/RTCs` в VC++) компилятор добавляет специальные значения ("канарейки") в стек при вызове функции, а после вызова проверяет, как там с ними дела, не изменились ли. Как именно он располагает переменные в стеке (и в стеке ли) — это дело компилятора. Например, VC++2019 сделал это так:

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_n$ = -40                       ; size = 8
_j$ = -24                       ; size = 8
_m$ = -8                        ; size = 4
_main   PROC

; 4    : {

    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 44                 ; 0000002cH
    push    edi
```

А это — размещение канареек

```
    lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-44]
    mov ecx, 11                 ; 0000000bH
    mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep stosd
```

Все. Когда вы выполняете

```
m += 1;
```

указатель смещается на размер `double`, *за* переменную `j` (да, на всякий случай, вы же помните, что в адресной арифметике +1 означает смещение в памяти на размер указываемого типа?), что некритично, пока вы не выполняете запись

```
*m = 1. - n + 1;
```

и тем самым портите "канарейку". Которая проверяется при выходе функции, и вы получаете соответствующее сообщение.

Мне удалось ответить на ваши вопросы?

P.S. В 64-разрядном коде получается примерно то же самое:

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT
m$ = 40
j$ = 72
n$ = 104
main    PROC

; 4    : {

$LN3:
    push    rdi
    sub rsp, 128                ; 00000080H
    lea rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
    mov ecx, 24
    mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep stosd
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое за ответ, пришло понимание почему выдаётся данная ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Тут стоит развеять превратные представления об адресной арифметике в С/C++.

После `m = &j;` указатель указывает на экземпляр объекта объект типа `double`. Этот указатель можно разыменовать, получая ссылку на исходный объект. Также к этому указателю можно применить адресную арифметику. В этом случае указатель рассматривается как указатель на первый элемент массива, состоящего из одного элемента типа `double`. Диапазон допустимых арифметических операций с ним ограничен прибавлением 0, при котором указатель не изменяется, и прибавление 1. При любой другой арифметической операции указатель выйдет за допустимые пределы и будет UB.

После прибавления 1 указатель будет указывать на элемент массива, который мог бы следовать сразу после последнего фактического элемента массива.  Разыменование полученного указателя является UB. Единственное, что с ним можно сделать, это сравнить с указателем на первый элемент этого массива, либо отнять 0 или 1, получая в последнем случае исходный указатель.

Таким образом, имея указатель на экземпляр объекта `double`, его можно использовать только для доступа к этому объекту, либо для итерации, как будто это массив из одного элемента. Любые попытки лазить по памяти в стороны - расстрел, то есть UB. Причем ответственность за корректность операций с указателями целиком лежит на программисте.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.